# how can I retrieve the current position of the vertices after they have been transformed?

Tags: opengl

How can I retrieve the current position of the vertices after they have been transformed? I have the following code....

How can I get the position of the "modelVertices" after the transform has been applied?

I am really after the screen coordinates so I can tell if a vert has been clicked by the mouse.

---

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

// save model transform matrix
GLfloat currentModelMatrix[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, currentModelMatrix);

// clear the model transform matrix
glLoadIdentity();

// rotate the x and y axis of the model transform matrix
glRotatef(rotateX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(rotateY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// reapply the previous transforms
glMultMatrixf(currentModelMatrix);

glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// since each vertes is defined in 3D instead of 2D parameter one has been 
// upped from 2 to 3 to respect this change.
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, modelVertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLU has the function `gluProject()` and `gluUnProject()`:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluProject.xml

If your platform doesn't have GLU you can always grab the code for [MESA](http://www.mesa3d.org/) and see how it is implemented.

Comment: Did you intend for one of those to be gluUnProject?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [feedback buffer](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html).